# Divergence of $1/r^2$: Mathematica yields 0, while the correct answer is a DiracDelta

Tags: physics, vector-calculus

In spherical coordinates, the divergence of a point charge is $4 \pi \delta (r)$, the three-dimensional Dirac delta function.  In `Div[1/r^2,{r,theta,phi},"Spherical"]`, however, *Mathematica* yields 0.  Is there any way I can get *Mathematica* to explicitly give me instead a `DiracDelta`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Do you mean `Laplacian` ? If so, your example is mentioned in the Possible Issues of the documentation for `DiracDelta`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks no, it should be divergence. He's dealing with the field (1/r^2), not the potential (1/r). But the issues coming up are indeed equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you just need to do that yourself by defining your own `div` function

```
 div[{Power[r_,-2],0,0},{r_,_,_},"Spherical"]=DiracDelta[r];
 div[args___]:=Div[args]

 div[{1/x^2,0,0},{x,y,z},"Spherical"]
```

> `DiracDelta[x]`